# HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error for ASP.NET Core 3.1.0 MVC application deploye on IIS version 10

Tags: asp.net, 500-error, iis-10

Here are the details about our development environment:

- DevExpress 20.2.3 (we are using DevExtreme)
- Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2019 (Version 16.4.6)
- ASP.NET Core 3.1.0
- AspNetCore.Mvc 3.1.0.0
- Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (RTM) –
- dotnet –version   3.1.300

Our Deployment Server environment details are:

- Windows Server 2016 Standard  64-bit OS
- dotnet –version   3.1.300
- IIS version 10

We aim to use build & deploy/package using dotnet commandline:

> Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17763.1697] (c) 2018 Microsoft
> Corporation. All rights reserved.
>
> C:\Windows\system32>D:
>
> D:>%comspec% /k "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2019\Enterprise\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat"
>
> ---
>
> ** Visual Studio 2019 Developer Command Prompt v16.8.2
> ** Copyright (c) 2020 Microsoft Corporation
>
> ---
>
> D:>cd D:\AppCodeArena\StrangeAcmeApplication\
>
> D:\AppCodeArena\StrangeAcmeApplication>dotnet --version
>
> 3.1.300
>
> D:\AppCodeArena\StrangeAcmeApplication>dotnet clean
>
> …..Output...blah….blah….blah…..Output... 0 errors
>
> D:\AppCodeArena\StrangeAcmeApplication>dotnet build  -c Release
> --runtime win10-x64    .\StrangeAcmeApplication.Uploaders.sln
>
> …..Output...blah….blah….blah…..Output... 0 errors
>
> D:\AppCodeArena\StrangeAcmeApplication>dotnet publish
> .\src\StrangeAcmeApplication.Uploaders\StrangeAcmeApplication.Uploaders.csproj
> --runtime win10-x64  --no-build -c Release  --output .\PublishedDirectory /p:DebugType=None /p:DebugSymbols=false
> /p:EnvironmentName=Development --self-contained true Microsoft (R)
> Build Engine version 16.6.0+5ff7b0c9e for .NET Core Copyright (C)
> Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
>
> StrangeAcmeApplication.Uploaders ->
> D:\AppCodeArena\StrangeAcmeApplication\PublishedDirectory\

Within the .\PublishedDirectory\appsettings.json is the following content:

> {   "Logging": {
> "LogLevel": {
> "Default": "Information",
> "Microsoft": "Warning",
> "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
> }   },   "AllowedHosts": "*" }

Within the .\PublishedDirectory\appsettings.Development.json is the following content:

> {   "Logging": {
> "LogLevel": {
> "Default": "Information",
> "Microsoft": "Warning",
> "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
> }   },   "ConnectionStrings": {
> "dbConnectionString": "Data Source=BlahSQLServerBlah;Initial Catalog=BlahDatabaseInstanceBlah;Persist Security Info=True;User
> ID=blahUserNameblah;Password=blahblah"
>
> } }

Finally within the .\PublishedDirectory\web.config, we have the following content:

```
< ?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <configuration>   <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false" >
    < system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath=".\InvestorCentral.Uploaders.exe" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess">
        <environmentVariables>
          <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="Development" />
        </environmentVariables>
      </aspNetCore>
    </system.webServer>   </location> </configuration>
```

However, I keep getting the following error when I deploy to IIS Server:

> HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
>
> The requested page cannot be accessed because the related
> configuration data for the page is invalid.
>
> Detailed Error Information:
>
> Module    IIS Web Core
>
> Notification    Unknown
>
> Handler    Not yet determined
>
> Error Code    0x8007000d
>
> Config Error
>
> Config File
> \?\D:\webSites\StrangeAcmeApplication.Published\web.config
>
> Requested URL    http://localhost:32769/
>
> Physical Path
>
> Logon Method    Not yet determined
>
> Logon User    Not yet determined
>
> Config Source:    -1:
> 0:

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49034308/asp-net-core-web-api-published-in-iis-after-moved-to-different-iis-server-pc-giv

Answer (score 0):

@lex-li  and @yiyi-you  Thank you for your comments.

I feel kind of silly because the problem was that the server in question needed to have .NET Core Hosting Bundle installed on it
(For my case, it's specifically .Net Core 3.1.12 Hosting Bundle for x64 bit ):

https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/3.1